# How to use Lambda function in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

In my application I have `RecyclerView` adapter and I want when **click** on Items, send some data to parent.
I want send **model** and **string**.
I write below codes, but after use show me error and I can't use this!

**Lambda function in adapter :**

```
    private var onItemClickListener: ((UserEntity) -> Unit)? = null
private var actionType: String? = null

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (UserEntity) -> Unit, type: String) {
    onItemClickListener = listener
    actionType = type
}
```

**Use this function in Activity :**

```
noteAdapter.setOnItemClickListener { listener: UserEntity, type: String ->
        }
```

**Error message Image :** 
[image]

How can I fix it and use this function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to both the objects i.e. `NoteEntity` & the `String` in the same listener, use like this :

```kotlin
private var onItemClickListener: ((UserEntity, String) -> Unit)? = null

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (UserEntity, String) -> Unit) {
    onItemClickListener = listener
}
```

After this, the lambda in the Activity should work fine.

```kotlin
noteAdapter.setOnItemClickListener { listener: UserEntity, type: String -> }
```